# How to fix the bug of command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

When I try to build my app with Xcode, an error interrupts the build process:

I am facing a below error

Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code facing an error while running an app:

[image: errors]

Comment: It seems that the linker can’t find FacebookCore and CreditCardForm. Maybe you opened the xcodeproj instead of the xcworkspace?

Comment: I am using xcworkspace and even after removing Facebook core and CreditCardForm it shows me same error.

Comment: I don't think you should remove them, because you use other libraries that need them. Maybe try to re-add them. Other things to try: Do Product > Clean, go back to a working version and see what changed, re-create a clean project.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but cleaning a product doesn't work for me

Comment: And the other two suggestions above?

Comment: I'm already trying re-adding the libraries but it throws me the same error I also remove the whole podfile but the code throws the same error. I'll be stuck on this error for days

Comment: Did a previous version work? Can you go back to it, and then see what's the diff? If not, Try creating a  new clean project. then adding the pods (but none of your code), and then adding your code little by little.

Comment: I'll get this code from someone else and I want to add some additional functionalities in this code

Comment: The clean slate method can still help. And if you got the repo (`.git` dir) in addition to the code, you can try the older versions.

Comment: Same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Any one solved this issue? I'm stuck with it for 2 days

Comment: Do you have any advice on this? I've the same error..